# How to change the image on click from database

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, uiimage

In my application, I have multiple images in an SQLite database since I want to change to the next image on button click.

Here is my code:

```
 -(void)Readthesqlitefile:(NSInteger *)sno
 {
sqlite3 *database;//database object
NSString *docpath=[self doccumentspath];//get sqlite path
const char *ch=[docpath UTF8String];//string to constant char UTF8string  main part to connect DB

if (sqlite3_open(ch, &database)==SQLITE_OK) {

    const char *chstmt="SELECT * FROM animal where rowid=  = %d",sno;

    sqlite3_stmt *sqlstmt;//to execute the above statement
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, chstmt, -1, &sqlstmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(sqlstmt)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            const char *Bname=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlstmt, 0);
            //converting const char to nsstring
            NSString *Bndname=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",Bname];
            NSLog(@"Brand Names=%@",Bndname);
            lb1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:Bndname];   

            NSUInteger legnt=sqlite3_column_bytes(sqlstmt, 1);

            if (legnt>0) {

                NSData *dt=[NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(sqlstmt, 1) length:legnt];
                clsimg=[UIImage imageWithData:dt];//converting data to image
                imager.image=clsimg;
            }
            else {
                clsimg=nil;
            }
     }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlstmt);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Button click function:

```
  -(IBAction)changenext
  {
  int j;
  for (j=1; j<10; j++)
  {
      [self Readthesqlitefile:j];
  }

  }
```

It's not working. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: I didn't understand your question , what is the issue ?

Comment: I need to change the image on each button click @MidhunMp

Comment: Ah, my head hurts (from this code)... Some advice: You won't get any useful answers here, if you don't ask a specific question. Throwing in a bunch of ugly code and asking "why doesn't it work?" (without specifying what it is that does not "work") won't help anybody. No offense.

Comment: The most obvious issue with your code is that you pass a *pointer* to an integer to your method, rather than the integer itself, which is almost certainly not what you intended.

Comment: Set static int j; in changeText method

Comment: And Query 
NSString *strQuery    = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM animal where rowid = %d",sno];
const char *chstmt = [strQuery UTF8String];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I understand that you need to change the image on each button click. If I'm correct then change the `changenext` method like:

```
-(IBAction)changenext
  {
    static int j = 0;
    if (j > 10)
    {
       j = 0;
    }
    [self Readthesqlitefile:j];
    j++;
  }
```

The above method will change the image on each button click. After displaying the last image it again starts from first image.

**EDIT:**

Also this line seems to be wrong

`const char *chstmt="SELECT * FROM animal where rowid=  = %d",sno;` .

There is no `==` operator in sqlite3 (I'm think so).
Replace that line by,

```
NSString *query    = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM animal where rowid = %d",sno];
const char *chstmt = [query UTF8String];
```

Comment: yu got my point but its not working,should i want to call ` [self Readthesqlitefile:j]' some where else. like view didload,please help me out

Comment: @iosdev: now what is the issue ? If the issue is not getting the image at first load, then call the method `[self changenext]` in the viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)Readthesqlitefile:(NSInteger *)sno
```

it take a pointer as parameter, but you pass a value.

```
const char *chstmt="SELECT * FROM animal where rowid=  = %d",sno;
```

Maybe this line should format it to a sql statement, where is the format code?

changenext part, i think Midhun MP's answer is the right solution

Comment: SELECT * FROM animal where rowid=  = %d i think this should be format the sno to %d, so the statement like SELECT * FROM animal where rowid==1 or something, but i can't find that code

Answer (score 0):

Well, we can't give the exact answer as all data is at your side but you can try this code to check the integrity of the data,

```
       NSData *dt=[NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(sqlstmt, 1) length:legnt];
       UIImage *clsimg=[UIImage imageWithData:dt]; //Creating new object for UIImage
       if(clsimg!=nil)
       {
           imager.image=clsimg; //I'm assuming that imager is added in IB or you've created it before assigning clsimg.
           clsimg = nil;
       }
       else
       {
           NSLog(@"No clsimg created, may problem in converting.");
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your UIImageView (imageView)

`[imageView setImage:clsimg];`